# Question regarding control variables in a serial mediation model

Tags: residuals, predictor, mediation, controlling-for-a-variable, mplus

i encountered questions regarding running a serial mediation model in mplus. my IV is ERS(excessive reasssurance seeking) DV is depression (DEP), my proposed two mediators are INU (internet use) and online social comparison (scfs). Also by running corrlation test, i found participants age, gpa related to INU and DEP. I was trying to control age, gpa, and maybe gender in my model. When i regress them on DEP in mplus (treat them as covariates?), the results seem fine.

The script is like "DEP on  gender age gpa ERS scfs INU ;
scfs on  ERS  INU ;
INU on   ERS;"

Then my supervisor said I can use the residual after I regress control variables on DEP, using residual as the new DV and see if the model still predict the same results. I ran regression in spss and got residuals use them as DV, but the relationship between scfs and DEP/also ERS and DEP turned from significant to non-significant. and that's not what i wanted, it's hard to explain the hypothesis in this case.

I was confused.

a) how to interpret the different results? does that mean previously significant results from scfs to dep is not only the effect of scfs, but scfs plus other control/confounding variables?

b) is it ok if i use the first approach, treating them as covariates in mplus?

c) when using residuals as new DV, mplus also didn't generate model fit, seems overfitting? but i need the model fit indicators to further run a multigroup analysis.

d) i learned from another study doing the same analysis, the author told me they regressed the control variables on both mediators and DV, i was wondering if that is necessary (in my sample, gpa significantly related to INU, but if i regress all control variables to mediators and DV, my model overfit again, degree of freedom is 0)

I was so confused by how should i treat the control variables, age, gpa, and gender (although gender not sig relatde to all other mediators and DV).

Thank you in advance if you could help me out!